# Automatically Restart MSTSC

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I've setup a computer for a client that automatically loads MSTSC as the default windows shell, and connects to the Terminal Server.

The problem is when they log out of the session, they must restart their computer to restart the rdp session.  I've locked down the desktop so they can't interact with the local computer.

How do I set it up so that MSTSC will automatically reconnect to the TS after they log out of the session?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could write a tiny wrapper program which does nothing else than run the Terminal Services Client in an endless loop (waiting for exit, obviously) and set that one as the shell.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
:foo
mstsc /v:someserver
goto :foo
```